# How do I compare value counts in each year when each year has a different sample size?

Tags: sample-size, survey

Let's say I went out each year asking people whether they really liked Pepsi, did not care about it, or hated it. But in the first year I asked people at my company when it was small, then the second year more employees came, each year the number of employees or my sample size increases; so the sample sizes are inequal to each other. And the number of people who agree to engage with me is not the same every year.

What do I do in order to show the number of people who hated, loved, or did not care about Pepsi in each year accurately?

The data currently looks like this:

```
|   Q's       | 2020 | 2021   | 2022  |
|=============|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|I hate pepsi | 1    | 21     | 3     |
|idc abt pepsi| 1    | 0      | 6     |
|I LOVE pepsi | 40   | 9      | 2     |

(In 2020 the company had 50 employees and 42 engaged with me)
(In 2021 the company had 200 employees and 30 engaged with me)
(In 2022 the company had 1000 employees and 11 engaged with me)
```

For example, in the year 2021, 21 people said they hated pepsi, it may seem that people hated it more than they did back in 2020 but this is only because the people that chose to engage with me that year were not fans by coincidence

Comment: If these are your actual data, you have almost no basis to draw inferences about all company employees in the years 2021 and 2022: the potential for selection bias is huge and the sample sizes are so small.

Comment: If you look at the proportions (percentages) of responses in each category for each year, that will mitigate the effect of having a different sample size for each year.  These percentages can be plotted to easily convey this information.

Comment: Are you more interested in actual views about the taste of Pepsi or are you interested in your success getting responses?